# What does "background" mean in a job interview?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "your own background" mean when an employer asks:

Please send us a PowerPoint presentation about **your own background**, your education and a detailed technical discussion of your thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "background" is your education, research, and work experience -- anything that might be relevant to the job.  They want you to tell them what *you* think is important for them to know about you.

Note that, depending on the job, this can also include things like your family history, hobbies, friends, awards, professional connections, military service, time spent overseas, charity work, and a wide range of other topics.